# Bind-mount and cryptsetup result in truncated root-path in /proc/self/mountinfo

Tags: proc, cryptsetup, bind-mount

I have an encrypted container containing an ext4 filesystem with a subdirectory which is bind-mounted at a later point in time. If I take look at `/proc/self/mountinfo`, the root-directory for the mount has a value I do not know the reason for.

Steps to reproduce:

```
cd /tmp
fallocate -l 1G container.luks
cryptsetup luksFormat container.luks
cryptsetup open --type=luks2 container.luks container
mkfs.ext4 /dev/mapper/container
mkdir /mnt/container
mount /dev/mapper/container /mnt/container/
mkdir /mnt/container/subdir
mkdir /tmp/abc
mount -o bind /mnt/container/subdir/ /tmp/abc
cat /proc/self/mountinfo

...
24 1 253:1 / / rw,noatime - ext4 /dev/dm-1 rw
...
56 24 253:5 / /mnt/container rw,relatime - ext4 /dev/mapper/container rw
57 24 253:5 /subdir /tmp/abc rw,relatime - ext4 /dev/mapper/container rw
```

As per [man 5 proc](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/procfs.5.html) field #4 is

> root: the pathname of the directory in the filesystem
> which forms the root of this mount.

Why is field #4 of the last line `/subdir` and not `/mnt/container/subdir`? Given the information for mount #57, how I am able to deduce, that mount #57 is a bind mount of a subdirectory of mount #56?

Sidenote: `umount -R /mnt/container` ignores mount #57.

---

Given the answer from Uncle Billy and several rereads of the relevant man-pages, my explanation is that `/subdir` is viewed from the root of a potential non-existent mount-point of device `253:5` somewhere in the system.
I hope that makes some sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> 56 24 253:5 / /mnt/container
> 57 24 253:5 /subdir /tmp/abc
> ```
>
> Given the information for mount `#57`, how I am able to deduce, that mount `#57` is a bind mount of a subdirectory of mount `#56`?

It's not. You don't deduce that.

The two mounts are only related by being mounts of the same filesystem/device (`253:5`); it's not that any of them is a "sub-mount" of the other or anything like that. They're independent of each other.

Comment: After reading your answer and the proc and mount manpage several times, I think I understand now and it slowly makes some kind of sense.